# How to fetch image from nested array of json in ListView builder in flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart, multidimensional-array

I am having json of this format:

```json
"data": [
    "images": [
        {
            id: "1",
            imageUrl: "http....."
        },
        {
            id: "2",
            imageUrl: "http....."
        },
        {
            id: "3",
            imageUrl: "http....."
        }
    ]
]
```

When I am trying to use imageUrl from this json using method:

```cpp
for(var i=0; i<data[index].images.length;i++){
    List img = [data[index].images[i].imageUrl];

    // And using img in Image.Network
    Image.Network(img[i]);
    // gives error Invalid value ; only valid value is 0:1
}
```

Comment: Please, add the source from your project or add a picture of your code. It's difficult to understand you code.

Comment: what is the expected result? when you have created an instance of Image.Network what would you like to do? If you explain to us the expected result we can provide you the best solution in that case